# whatsapp dbs with root or with out root

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I wonder if I could get whatsapp msgz on 5 OR 5+ VERSION programmatically. I've searched could not find any reference who have tested and said it is working code with root or with out root.

Regards
Michael

Comment: you can find databases in /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases

Comment: thanks but how do I find a key for decrypt those files.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: those files will not be encrypted.

Comment: @DeepakGangwar I didnt get you , what do you mean by those files will not be encrypted? are the already in decrypted form?

Comment: @MichaelKhana yes you can directly open them however you will need root to access the folder